# Identifying properties of a graph by looking at the adjacency matrix.

Tags: graph-theory

Lets say you have a graph G with n vertices. It has an adjacency matrix A.
How can you tell by looking at the adjacency matrix if the graph G has any loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: A loop $v=v_0$, $v_1$, $\ldots$, $v_d = v$ will give a term $1$ in the expression for the  entry  $(v,v)$ in the matrix $A^d$.